# Algorithm to determine if two colored graphs are isomorphic?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, algorithm

I have two (vertex-)colored graphs. I want to determine if they are isomorphic, with the condition that the isomorphism respects the colors of the vertices. Moreover, I want the algorithm to output the isomorphism found, if it exists. How can I do this in Mathematica?

I know the function `FindGraphIsomorphism` allows me to find an isomorphism between two uncolored graphs. But I don't think it works for colored graphs the way I want it to.